# Why is Mill's wife calling on the 7th day in the movie Se7en?

Tags: se7en

The last day in the story of *Se7en*, shortly before John surrendered, a colleague says to Mills that his wife has called and that he should take a phone secretary. Why is she calling? Is John at their home at this moment and is she asking for help? Could the answer to this call have saved her life?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, maybe not. We will never know.

Seeing that John Doe had planned all his crimes, it's possible that she was asking for help while he was there, perhaps Doe weaselled his way into Mill's house and she got suspicious and just called to confirm with him, or perhaps it's none of these and she called for a different reason.

Even if he answered, we don't know what Doe had planned, maybe she would be already dead by the time the cops got there, had he planned this way. Maybe the movie ended as it did *because* Mills didn't answer the call, so Doe adapted his plan a bit.

There's nothing else in the movie to help figuring this one out.